# How to print the JSON output in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to get an output for the code

```
app.get('/_browse', function(req, res){

    var filter = {};
    var type = req.query["type"] || '';
    var nodeValue =  (req.query["nodeValue"]) ? req.query["nodeValue"] : "";
    var nodeApi =  (req.query["nodeApi"]) ? req.query["nodeApi"] : "";
    var node =  (req.query["node"]) ? req.query["node"] : "";
    var callback = req.query["callback"] || '';
    /*var mapobject = {
        kingdom : "phylum",
        phylum : "class",
        class : "order",
        order : "family",
        family : "genus",
        genus : "specificEpithet",

    };*/
    var text = {
            text: nodeValue,
            specimenCount: 'count',
            nodeApi: nodeApi,
            nodeValue: nodeValue,
                }

    var mapobject = {

        phylum : "family",
        family : "genus",
        genus : "specificEpithet",

    };
    var type = mapobject[nodeApi];  
    var nvalue = {};
    if(nodeValue != ''&& nodeApi != '') {
     nvalue[nodeApi] = nodeValue;
    }
    var typeValue = "$"+ type;

collection.aggregate(

        { $match : nvalue},
        { $group : {
            _id : typeValue,
            count : { $sum : 1 },
        }},
        {$sort: {_id: 1}},
    function(err, results) {
        /*results[0]['text'] = text;
        console.log("text values",results[0]['text']);*/
            /*var text = {
            text: "Aceraceae ",
            specimenCount: 'count',
            nodeApi: "Family",
            nodeValue: "Aceraceae",
                }
            results['text'] = text;
            console.log("text values",results.text);
            */  
        (var i in results){
            if(results = text){
                results.text =  nodeValue;
                results.specimenCount = 'count';
                results.nodeApi = nodeApi;
                results.nodeValue = nodeValue;
            console.log("results",results.text);
            }
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        if (callback != '') {
            res.end(callback + '(' + JSON.stringify({success: true, rows: results}) + ')');

        } else {
                res.end(JSON.stringify({success: true, rows: results}));


            }

    });

});
```

like...

```
    results: [{
       text: "Acanthaceae (300)",
       specimenCount: "300",
       nodeApi: "Family",
       nodeValue: "Acanthaceae",
       filter: {
           StateProvince: "Louisiana",
           Taxonomy: "",
           Phylum: "dicot"
       }
   },
```

I did my coding like this way but it is not giving the output.
It need to process the results to make this output.
Please help me to get the output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print `results` like above you can do :

1. `console.log("Result: %j", results);`
2. `console.log(require('util').inspect(results, false, null));`